# Gitlab does not respond when port is specified for SSL

Tags: ssl, https, gitlab

I'm running the Omnibus version of Gitlab in docker.

I've edited my `gitlab.rb` file so as to enable https by prefixing `external_url` with `https://`. This seems to work well enough. However, when I also add my port to the URL:

external_url = 'https://www.example.com:12345'

My browser shows me a "connection refused" error. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default port where GitLab is running, you have to put this in your `gitlab.rb` file :

```
gitlab_rails['gitlab_host'] = 'example.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_port'] = 12345
gitlab_rails['gitlab_https'] = true
```

After you set this parameters, you'll have to run a `# gitlab-ctl reconfigure`

Also take a look at `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/config.yml`: you can find here interesting parameters for: the SSL certificates path

```
http_settings:
  #user: someone
  #password: somepass
  ca_file: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  ca_path: /etc/pki/tls/certs
  self_signed_cert: false
```

Comment: It seems like your first sentence is incorrect, because I am able to break my Gitlab by changing `external_url`.